# Url rewrite with mod_jk

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting, mod-jk

In a php application, I use the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^test-([0-9]+)\.html$ test.php?id=$1
```

After I access this by this rule:

http://localhost/testphp/test-1.html

I get the expected page and the url in browser stays in the same:

http://localhost/testphp/test-1.html

But if I config the same rule with mod_jk:

```
RewriteRule ^/testjk/test-([0-9]+)\.html$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/testjk/test.jsp?id=$1
```

then after I visit the page using the rewritten url:

http://localhost/testjk/test-1.html

the url in browser will jump to:

http://localhost/testjk/test.jsp?id=1

Anyone knows how can I make the jk one perform like the php one?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to work by changing the rule to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/testjk/test-([0-9]+).html$ /testjk/test.jsp?id=$1 [L,PT]
```

Comment: Pretty sure PT implies the L flag now (maybe not at the time of this answer.)  I would think the "L" would not be needed.